# I get this error when i make the libobjcipc. " 'MSFindSymbol' is invalid in C99 "

Tags: ios, iphone, jailbreak, theos, tweak

https://github.com/a1anyip/libobjcipc

I download the libobjcipc from github,and make it,but get an error say  not found. I copy the framework to theos/include from mac's usr/include. Then I make it,it say "launch.h not found",I copy it to theos/include from usr/include.
But I get a new error when I make it.

Follows is this error:

```
    IPC.m:83:27: error: implicit declaration of function 'MSFindSymbol' is invalid
    in C99 [-Werror,-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
    MSHookFunction(((int *)MSFindSymbol(NULL, "_BSAu...
    1 error generated.
    make[3]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/IPC.m.1f7dac36.o] Error 1
    make[2]: *** [.theos/obj/armv7/libobjcipc.dylib] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
    make: *** [libobjcipc.all.library.variables] Error 2
```

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you have an up to date Substrate header ([here](http://iphonedevwiki.net/index.php/Theos/Setup#Missing_Substrate_symbols)'s the troubleshooting section on the iPhoneDevWiki).

Comment: Is this reason.I really appreciate your help.